# Recurse through a directory with php and add a file to many zips

Tags: php

This will be simple for someone, so hope you don't mind my asking here, I have some php code like so:

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('myfiles1.zip) === TRUE) {
    $zip->addFile('readme.txt', 'readme.txt');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

I would like to make it recurse through the directory it is in and add the same file "readme.txt" to all the zips inside it.

Comment: Iterate over the directory's contents, unzip all zips, add file, rezip. Which part you having issues with?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just how to do that. Can you add some code to show how it is done?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php then something similiar to above

Comment: OK, so that seems to have done the trick. Thanks.